# Interpolate weights in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

A have two models with the same architecture but trained with a different losses.

These models give different results. I want to «balance» between these models combining their weights lineary:

```
combined_weights = k * weights_a + (1 - k) * weights_b
```

The problem I working on allows for this approach. It's argued that this approach is more efficient than interpolating the outputs.

I also have a PyTorch implementation of this approach:

```
k = 0.3
model_a = torch.load(...)
model_b = torch.load(...)
combined_model = OrderedDict()

for i, v_a in model_a.items():
    v_b = model_b[i]
    combined_model[i] = k * v_a + (1 - k) * v_b

torch.save(combined_model, ...)
```

How can I do the same in TensorFlow?
I've tried to do it combining weights of my models:

```
k = 0.3
weights_a = model_a.get_weights()
weights_b = model_b.get_weights()

combined_weights = k * weights_a + (1 - k) * weights_b

combined_model.set_weights(combined_weights)
```

But got an error at `k * weights_a`:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: Since weights_a and weights_b here are lists, you have to write a for-loop or something to retrieve each weight tensor and modify it one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the type mismatch. Both `weights_a` and `weights_b` are just regular python lists that can't be multiplied by floats (this is not the operation that you are looking anyway).

Weights are stored in `ndarray` format as elements of those lists. Probably the easiest way to make it work is to loop through the weights and perform the operation for each `ndarray`

```
k = 0.3

weights_a = ...
weights_b = ...
combined = []

for i in range(len(weights_a)):
    c = k * weights_a[i] + (1 - k) * weights_b[i]
    combined.append(c)
```